# How to handle spaces in slot values in google action

Tags: action, slot

I have an action which has a parameter type site_name, where the user asks
details of his site name. e.g. connectivity status of "demo".(demo is the
site name).The action backend will call third party API to get the
details of site name. The site names may be anything which include special
chars (`-`,`_`,`+`,`&`) and site name can also contain spaces (two word et...)

One of the issue which I am facing is the google device is capturing the site with space.
Example : if we have the site name "demosite"(with out space),
Google device is always capturing with space. i.e "demo site". As a work around.
I use words and synonym for "demosite" but here we are facing two issues:

1. How many site names should I add as synonym since every user has more
   number of site names and for every site name we can't add the synonym.
2. For site names "demo+site", "demo_site", "demo-site" sometimes google
   device is capturing demo plus site, demo underscore site, demo hyphen site.
   Here also I can add the synonyms but of all the other site names (ex 1000
   site names) how can I add and handle this?